# How do i create a wifi - hotspot using my wired connection?

Tags: wireless

How do i create a wifi - hotspot using my wired connection ? I went to network settings - Wirless and clicked on start hotspot but my mobile phone is not able to detect the hotspot.

Answer (score 0):

That's because it's operating in ad-hoc mode. Androids don't work well with ad-hoc networks unless you load them with custom firmware. I use Cyanogenmod. It can detect ad-hoc networks. However, ad hoc networks are EXTREMELY slow.